# Castle Windsor: How to test that all registered components are resolvable?

Tags: testing, castle-windsor

I would like to write a test that just ensures that all components registered to my WindsorContainer can indeed be resolved.  Anyone have any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: May you should look at Ayande's Service Bus (http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/17/rhino-service-bus.aspx). He is a big TDD fan, and heavily use Windsor.

Comment: I am well aware of Ayende's offerings. What does this have to do with the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See these posts from Bil Simser:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2008/06/04/the-first-spec-you-should-write-when-using-castle.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2008/06/27/testing-castle-windsor-mappings-part-deux.aspx

Comment: Its always either you or bittercoder that gets these. Thanks a lot, I could take it to the Windsor board but every time Ayende answers a question I feel like he's mad at me for not living on the super-programmer plane that he's on.

Comment: mausch, do you check SO every few minutes to see if there are any new Castle questions, or you just append to be here when they're asked. It seems like every time there's a new one, you already answered it :)

Comment: @Krzysztof: I track a few tags via RSS and check them every couple of hours or so.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer the link seems to be busted.